# Command: move all files inside a directory to another directory (including hidden files)?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, shell, mv

I tried to move all files inside a directory to another directory like this:

```
$ mv /directory_one/* /directory
```

However, the hidden files (such as .htaccess) in /directory_one won't be moved.

What is the right command to do so?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/62141/linux-how-to-move-all-files-from-current-directory-to-upper-directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
mv /directory_one/* /directory_one/.* /directory
```

It will move regular files and dotfiles.